# Carrot2 - Entering private PubMed api key

Tags: api-key, pubmed, carrot2

I'm using Carrot2-Workbench 3.16.3.0 for PubMed queries.

Mostly, I run into the "payload" and "api key" problem. I have a private PubMed key. But, neither the Workbench nor the online version allows me to enter it.

Is there any easy way to use it, or is it hard-coded in the source?

Comment: Carrot2 uses PubMed's [ESearch](https://dataguide.nlm.nih.gov/eutilities/utilities.html#esearch) utility -- would your private PubMed key be compatible with that API or it's for a different PubMed API?

Comment: I've used my API key together with R packages that make use of PubMed's ESearch utilities. So, yes I suppose so. I generated it after logging into MyNCBI.

Comment: The lack of the api_key parameter in ESearch API documentation confused me a bit, hence the question. I implemented the API support in the on-line demo (see the answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous versions did not support PubMed API keys, the latest on-line version does, it's under the "options" button:

[image: PubMed API key in Carrot2 search demo]

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your quick feedback very much and will give it a try.
Do you intend to include this feature also in a future version of the carrot2-Workbench?

Comment: In the upcoming 4.0.0 release, we'll be phasing out the desktop-based Workbench and replacing it with a browser-based counterpart, which you will be able to run locally or access on-line. The previous versions will remain available for download, but we most likely won't be adding new features to them.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification. The current online version has a limit of 350 for max results, that the desktop-based Workbench does not have. Will the upcoming 4.0.0 release also have a max result limit. I think, that with a personal API key this might be not necessary.

Comment: What is the maximum number of results you're processing?

Comment: The current project consists of up to ca. 650 references.

Comment: I've just increased the PubMed limit in the on-line version to 1000 results.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your work! Works perfectly.